# Direction of Shear Stress on the periphery of a circular section beam

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, structural-analysis, beam

*The Question is from shear stresses in beams*

Consider a beam made of circular cross section, in which at any cross section the shear force is V.

[image]

The textbook I'm following states that -

> When a beam has a circular cross section, we can no longer
> assume that the shear stresses act parallel to the y axis. For
> instance, we can easily prove that at point m (on the boundary of the
> cross section) the shear stress $\tau$ must act tangent to the boundary.
> This observation follows from the fact that the outer surface of the
> beam is free of stress, and therefore the shear stress acting on the
> cross section can have no component in the radial direction.

**I'm having trouble with understanding why the shear stress at m, should be tangent to the boundary.**

Say I enlarge the element,

[image]

and assume that the shear stress acts along y axis. this shear stress can be resolved into tangential and radial components to get $\tau_t$ and $\tau_r$. The book says this $\tau_r$ can't be balanced by any other stress in the radial direction and hence it must be zero. But it could happen that a normal stress is developed on the surface as shown in (b), which balances $\tau_r$

Comment: What is the definition of shear stress?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source material?

Comment: To further elaborate upon my question, the quantity $\tau$ is figure (a) is not a shear stress and the quantity $\tau_x$ in Figure (b) is, by definition, a normal stress.  The implication is that you don't have a clear idea of what a shear stress is.  Perhaps you should return to the part of the book that defines this quantity?

Comment: Biswajit, this might clear things up - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vdIOKVY4wofJDLtgQSirwrj5BWeOaqQC/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @r13 From the book 'Mechanics of Materials by Gere and Goodno' - http://160592857366.free.fr/joe/ebooks/Mechanical%20Engineering%20Books%20Collection/STRENGTH%20OF%20MATERIALS/MechaMatBreif.pdf , Pg. No. - 319, Section 5.8

Comment: I think you misunderstand.  I know what the author is talking about and why the author is correct.  I'm just pointing out that you have to think a bit about the basic definitions to understand why the author is correct.  You probably need to just look at a book on elasticity (or advanced mechanics of materials) to get the ideas clear in your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a small element of the circular shaft and apply the shear stress $\tau_1$ in an arbitrary direction on the surface of the cut. The shear stress can be resolved into a radial shear stress $\tau_r$ and tangential shear stress $\tau_t$ as shown below.

[image]

We recall the state of shear stresses on a cube element - when shear stress presents on one plane, there must exist a shear stress on the face normal to that plane. In this case, there must be a shear stress $\tau_z$ corresponding to $\tau_r$, however, we know that the stress on the outermost surface of an element is zero, from this realization we can conclude that $\tau_r$ must be zero as well, so only $\tau_t$ remains effective.

Note that this phenomenon is valid for shear stress on the perimeter only.

Comment: Thanks r13, do you happen to know how other shear stresses on the c/s will be oriented wrt the y axis? or if you know about any source?

Comment: As noted, other than the surface layer, there will exist a tau_z, thus the tangential orientation of the shear stress is no longer valid. I don't know if this answers your question or not.